# Build statically linked binary on gentoo

Tags: gentoo, static-linking

I'm looking for a way to build a fully statically linked binary on Gentoo.

The build system is Meson. I tries `--prefer-static` and `--default_library=static` with no success.

A possible obstacle is that some libraries (e.g. `libevent` and `glib`) don't have the static versions installed (unlike `libc` and a few other libraries). Should I rerun `emerge` with some special flags?

Comment: After installing the static versions of the libraries you need, the `--static` option should help.

Comment: @waltinator Yes but is there a standard way to install the static versions of all the necessary libraries with dependencies?

Comment: See answer below.  The answer will assume that you have completed the Handbook Phase of an install.

Answer (score 0):

### Support Static Linking For All Applicable Packages

Instead of just compiling the needed libraries using `--static` and Gentoo specific `static-libs`, a safer approach is to make your entire system static. As you can see on the [Online Package Repository](https://packages.gentoo.org/useflags/static), many packages support a `static` USE flag.

### What Is Static Linking?

Static Linking is useful for programs on embedded systems, or devices where the user doesn't have access to certain Application Libraries.  On Windows based systems these libraries are commonly stored as files with a `.DLL` extension, short for `Dynamic Linking Library` On Linux, these are commonly stored as files with the extension of `.so` or `.so.versionNumberOfProgramThatUsesLibrary`
(short for Shared Object).  When compiled statically, the library files discussed above are shipped with the compiled program, allowing the user to copy the completed program to say a home directory with full write access, and the program will use the library file in that home directory instead of the same library on the host system that the user does not have access to. For a more in-depth look at Static vs. Dynamic Linking see: [What are the differences between static and dynamic (shared) library linking?](https://cs-fundamentals.com/tech-interview/c/difference-between-static-and-dynamic-linking)

### Heed The Warning

In the First Years of Gentoo, users were able to build their systems from tarballs that were in different stages, and I'm proud to say I've done it once or twice, using a Stage one when that was the accepted procedure.  See [Stage tarball on the Gentoo Wiki.](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Stage_tarball).  The warning that reads:

> do not set this during bootstrap!! Causes binaries to be statically linked instead of dynamically

applies to stage 1.  It's there to avoid the [Chicken or Egg Conundrum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg).  You can't include library files with programs using static libraries, or with programs with no libraries, because there is no way to build a static library file using static libraries.  In other words: **You must use Dynamically Linked Libraries from the host system in order to build and include static libraries with programs**.

### How to Do This on Gentoo

1. Complete the [install handbook for your chosen architecture](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:Main_Page).
2. Fine-tune your USE Flags and/or profile (A great tool for this is [app-portage/ufed](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/app-portage/ufed), short for USE Flag Editor) for your newly installed system, but DO NOT ADD `static` or `static-libs`.  This allows you to add a desktop environment, sound support, kernel rebuild etc, and allows the base `@system` set to keep using the dynamic libraries.

   - **Make sure** step 2 completes without error.  Note also that you can split up Step 2 into multiple parts, for example, enable desktop support, build in that using `emerge` and rerun `ufed`, and add in some type of graphics support, then rerun `emerge` again.
3. Run `ufed` one more time and add the `static` and `static-libs` USE Flags.  Then issue an `emerge -ea` for `--empty-tree --ask` to rebuild your entire tree and update every package that supports the `static` and `static-libs` USE Flag

I call this method the "2-pass bullet proofing method a.k.a the 2-pass compile."  The first pass in step 2 ensures that nothing is broken at the start of step 3.  If the second pass in step 3 should fail in some way, you are free to fix the failure and either Restart Step 3 or use `emerge --resume` and continue on knowing that nothing in the preceding steps was broken by your failure (the failed package is never installed until the failure is fixed).

### Meson

If we look at [dev-util/meson](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/dev-util/meson) in the package repository, we can see from the [ebuild](https://gitweb.gentoo.org/repo/gentoo.git/tree/dev-util/meson/meson-1.3.0-r2.ebuild) that it doesn't directly support the `static` USE Flag, but many of it's dependencies support `static` or `static-libs`, which would accomplish what you want.